# UIWebView does not respond to calls in "applicationWillResignActivity"

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, cordova

I am developing a web-app in iOS using PhoneGap. I need to make a javascript function call when the application goes into the background.

I am calling the function from "applicationWillResignActivity" method, but its not executing till the app comes to the foreground next time. Any other non-javascript code is getting executed. This happens only when I press home button. In other cases, like pressing power button when the app is running, and pressing the home button twice, the javascript function gets executed.

Is there some constraint over UIWebView of such kind? Can someone please tell if there is a way to make javascript work when user presses Home button?

Comment: Anyone else please.... :P   But seriously, this is important. Is there anyway I can delay the going-to-the background action so that webview has enough time to execute that piece of javascript code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is no way to capture such event. So just to self-answer this question, that there indeed is no delegate method to run JS code when app goes into background.